# Sending a message using username instead of recipient_id (Python Twitter API)

Tags: python, json, twitter, python-requests, twitterapi-python

I am having trouble figuring out how to send a message by username(screen_name) instead of "recipient_id".

The only real difference I made my to replace "recipient_id" with "screen_name" but no luck.

Note: I have generated my keys

```py
import requests, requests_oauthlib, sys

import json


def verify_credentials(auth_obj):

    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
    response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_obj)
    return response.status_code == 200


def init_auth():

    auth_obj = requests_oauthlib.OAuth1(consumer_key,
                                        consumer_secret,
                                        access_token,
                                        access_secret)

    if verify_credentials(auth_obj):
        print('Validated credentials OK')
        return auth_obj
    else:
        print('Credentials validation failed')
        sys.exit(1)

def send_dm(auth_obj): 

         url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json'
         payload = {"event":
                   {"type": "message_create",
                    "message_create":
                        {"target": {"screen_name": "***USERNAME****"},
                         "message_data": {"text": "Hello from class!, Just wanted to message you to test"}
                         }
                    }
               }

    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), auth=auth_obj)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return json.loads(response.text)
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    auth_obj = init_auth()
    since_id = 1
    message = send_dm(auth_obj)
    print(message)
```

The error I am receiving is the following

```
Validated credentials OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/guzma/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/twitter_worldclock.py", line 153, in <module>
    message = send_dm(auth_obj)
  File "C:/Users/guzma/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/twitter_worldclock.py", line 76, in send_dm
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "F:\Client-Server Computing\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the Twitter API. The [Direct Messages create endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event) requires a recipient ID, not a screen name.

> **message_create.target.recipient_id** (required)
> The ID of the user who should receive the direct message.

You'll need to use the user lookup endpoint to convert between screen name and user ID in order to pass in the recipient ID.